# How to Clear Live ID Cookies

Tags: adfs2.0

So we are using ADFS in a public facing SharePoint 2010 site. One of the supported logins is via Live ID. We have found that if a user logs into Live ID site like Hotmail prior to reaching our site, the following happens:

1. Our site thinks that the user is not logged in because the ADFS LS cookie is not present
2. When we click on Sign In and ADFS redirects us to Live ID, the Live ID login process detects its cookie and automatically logs us in using the prior user's email. We actually want to use another email address.
3. Even if we clear our cookies, the above behavior persists

We have tried the following on Windows 7 successfully:

1. Clear the browser cookies
2. Delete all files from %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\

And then Live ID correctly asks the user to login.

However, the above folder does not exist in a Windows 8 computer where this behaviour can be reproduced in IE 10.

So I really need to know the **name and location** of the Live ID cookie so I can hunt for it and destroy it to get the sign in prompt.

The ideal solution is that ADFS destroy the cookies correctly. The ADFS team is building a diagnostic page to delete their cookies but I do not think they will be able to destroy the Live ID cookie as it is not from their domain. If I can find its location, we can live with manual instructions for now.

**Update**
Found an answer. The trick is to go to live.com and click on signout first and then go to the SharePoint application. Not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: you can't delete cookies - you can expire them

Answer (score 0):

Update Found an answer. The trick is to go to live.com and click on signout first and then go to the SharePoint application. Not the best solution, but it works